# Should reviewers approve edits that only obfuscate private info like email?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, privacy

I came across this [proposed edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8784503) in the queue that only obfuscated the OP's email address.

It did get approved by 3 reviewers (including me), however 1 reviewer rejected it with the reason:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

The first sentence of that reason is right, but I believe the second is not. Readability wasn't harmed, no argument there. However, I don't believe that an *improvement in privacy* is superfluous.

There are other edits that could be done to improve the question, mainly regarding the grammar which is consistent with a non-native English user. However, the question is clear and understandable enough in its present form to be answered.

Personally, when I see a brand new question like this, I'll take care of the privacy concerns with a quick edit, then follow up with additional edits to improve the question *if time allows*.

- Nobody needs to approve my edits, so I'm not putting a drain on community review resources.
- Scrapers are less likely to pick up and propagate the private info if we edit it quickly enough. (RSS feeds would defeat this.)
- I think the immediate (and if luck holds, long-lasting) benefits of keeping the OP's email address private outweigh the need for any other edits.

So what does everyone think? Are edits that only hide email addresses and other personal information different than other minor / incomplete edits? Should privacy-related edits be approved even if they don't address possibly major readability or formatting concerns?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reject it, unless it's really sensitive information, in which case you should **immediately inform a moderator for redacting the revision-history**.
And if you feel the urge, make a good edit instead.

Redacting that email alone isn't useful, at least as a suggested edit, especially as long as there's lots of grammar to clean up and also some fluff (like half the prose) to nuke.

Comment: Ironic twist, as you edited the question... I had edited it but not submitted the change yet because I was writing this question. I picture you as a S.O. [Rick Wakeman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rick_Wakeman), surrounded by computer keyboards, able to type on 4 of them at the same time...

Comment: How does one know if it is sensitive enough or not for the person who made the edit?

Answer (score 8):

Just me personally but I would say that an edit made for *privacy* reasons such as that is not superfluous. That being said, if the editor only changed that part of the question and left other as you said *"major readability or formatting concerns"* within the question then maybe the better suited response should be the <kbd>Approve and Edit</kbd> or, to not reward them for their laziness the <kbd>Reject and Edit</kbd> buttons.

Comment: +1, depending on just how flagrant their laziness is. If the other issues with the post are a little subtler, it's not so big a deal to let a marginal edit skate through with +2 once in a while.