# How to review "redacted for privacy concerns"?

Tags: discussion

Going through the review queue for *Suggested Edits* I have stumbled upon a curious comment to [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21246247):

> boss made me take out items with names showing.

To my understanding of the SO terms and conditions, once it is published, it belongs to the world, so to say. Hence, I've voted to reject the edit.

However, I personally don't find it ethical to post information about someones income, so my question is: what should have been the right decision in this case?

I have read about [Should reviewers approve edits that only obfuscate private info like email?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/299212/5366641), but I cannot really find an explanation for this case.

More details:

The image was posted as part of the question (and edited out by the OP). With the suggested edit the OP tries to remove it from the answer as well.

The author of the answer is not the one to blame in my opinion.

Comment: If the post truly contains names that shouldn't be on SO, I think the best course of action would be to delete the post and ask them to repost it altogether. An edit won't be enough (the removed names are still present in the edit history anyway).

Comment: There is leeway for this.  But the editor lives three thousand miles away from the post owner, we need better evidence that this isn't vandalism.

Comment: @HansPassant, please read the details I have added after better examination of the case.

Comment: Hmya, I did look at the image before posting the comment.  I think everybody is *much* better off if the boss talks to the post owner and explains what kind of info is considered proprietary.  That solves two problems.

Comment: @HansPassant, half moon yacht association?

Comment: [Related Stack Exchange Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132117/what-should-i-do-if-a-user-posts-sensitive-information-as-part-of-a-question-or)

Comment: It's worth noting that the OP of that question would have a much better time of it if they simply replaced their data set with a different data set containing entirely public information that demonstrated all of the same problems, rather than trying to remove the data set from the question entirely.  My uneducated reading of the question leads me to believe such a data set wouldn't be hard to make up or find from a different source.

Comment: @Servy, I think that would be indeed more appropriate.